# Why couldn't Harry see his arm supporting the lamp the first time he wore the Cloak of Invisibility?

Tags: harry-potter, invisibility-cloak

> The library was pitch-black and very eerie. Harry lit a lamp to see his way along the rows of books. The lamp looked as if it was floating along in midair, and even though Harry could feel his arm supporting it, the sight gave him the creeps.
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and The Sorcerers Stone* (1997)</sub>

Didn't the cloak cover his head too? (As in the movie - although his arm was visible in the movie.)

If it covers his head, then that means can indeed see everything inside and outside the cloak, *including his arm*.

Answer (score 19):

It makes sense if the cloak works at the boundary rather than the content, and it's more of a traditional cloak (draped around the shoulders with a hood pulled over the head).

Someone inside it can see through the hood of the cloak to the world around them, but they cannot see back inside the fabric that is draped over the arm.

The fact that the arm and the eyes are both inside is irrelevant, as there is a layer of cloak around the arm. If both arm and head are pulled into the same space inside the cloak, so there is a direct line of sight to the arm, the  it would indeed be visible.

Comment: This feels more like your own headcanon than anything supported by the novel/s. Can you offer any textual evidence to back this up?

Comment: @Valorum As HP has a soft magic system, we'll never know for sure. However, this seems to be a very plausible explanation and aligns up pretty nicely with the evidence in the movies. The Golden Trio was definitely capable of seeing each other while under the Cloak.

Comment: @Roberto - I was thinking more of examples of Harry being under the cloak and seeing parts of himself in other contexts

Comment: @Valorum: Given that Harry sees things outside of the cloak, light passes into the cloak into Harry's eyes. Given that Harry cannot be seen, light does not pass out of the cloak (from Harry to an outside observer's eyes). Clearly, the cloak is one-way and the other way completely blocks light. The example being asked about requires light to travel from Harry's arm to Harry's eyes, **both ways** through the one-way cloak (inside at the arm -> outside -> inside at Harry's eyes). The nature of turning invisible would obviously be maintained.

Comment: @Flater - If it's obvious then it should be super-easy to provide evidence to back it up

Comment: @Flater The cloak can't work with _actual_ light, or you would be able to see Harry's retinas as shadows on the other side.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 You would just see a very slightly darker area where the cloak is. Even just 0.1% of light passed would be enough to see once eyes adapt to it. But going through the cloak a second time brings that down to 0.0001%, which would be invisible against the brighter surroundings.

Comment: Every time you try to drag real physics into a discussion...

Comment: @Valorum: The text itself backs it up. Here's an example: "The lamp looked as if it was floating along in midair, and even though Harry could feel his arm supporting it, the sight gave him the creeps."

Comment: @MooingDuck - I meant an example **other than precisely the same one given in the question**

Comment: @Valorum: Why?  It proves that this is basically the only viable explanation

Comment: @Flater It's magic, not physics.   It can't 'block' light for a few reasons, one being that if he's not standing on the cloak, then the floor would be black to an outside observer since it was covered by the cloak.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat No it wouldn't. People outside the cloak see _through_ the cloak at what's behind. So if Harry stands cloaked inbetween you and me, I see you and you see me. When we look at the ground under Harry's feet, we just see the ground like we normally would.

Comment: @Valorum: Something being trivially consistent does not inherently imply that there is explicit confirmation on the topic.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: You've zoomed in several levels of granularity between the basic workings of the cloak and your (factually physically correct) point about the shadows of Harry's retinae. Not saying you're wrong but rather than an inconsistency on that level does not inherently prove a (meaningful) inconsistency on the simpler level of how the cloak makes you invisible.

Comment: @Flater - If it's trivially consistent then it should be trivially simple to prove it.

Comment: @Valorum It's magic. It lets (all) the light through _and_ it lets Harry see stuff. Harry Potter magic doesn't run on physics: brooms have a speed limit, there's a _luck_ potion, and Death gives people trinkets. It is (sometimes) consistent with its own internal logic, though, and the invisibility cloak from the books is an example.

Comment: @Valorum Consistency is the default expectation. The onus of proving an inconsistency is on you. I cannot conclusively prove the negative case as a matter of logical fact. I am not willing to go back and forth with you on this any further since you're effectively copy-pasting your responses.

Comment: @Flater that doesn't make sense.  If Harry can see the floor under his feet, then it is inside the cloak's field and the cloak is blocking the light and should be showing what is under the field.  If he can't see the floor that would make sense.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat I don't understand your point. A person on the inside of the cloak can see effectively everything that a normal person would in a cloak-less situation. The cloak only hides what's in the cloak from the sight of anyone outside the cloak. What Harry can see is not up for debate here as far as I'm aware. Furthermore, if Harry also stands on the cloak, he can still see through it and see the ground, just like he can see what's ahead of him.

Comment: My point is that it's magic, not physics.   The only way what you say makes sense is that the cloak knows what is 'inside it'.   The cloak knows that the wearer and their shoes are inside it, and the ground is not.  Say there is a piece of gum stuck to the floor 5 ft from harry.  At this point the cloak has no effect from any point of view.  Now say that Harry walks over to it and stands with his feed on either side.   Is the gum inside the cloak or not?   Does it disappear to other people?  If not then it is 'outside' so it would look like anything else 'outside' the cloak, which would look..

Comment: ...different from his shoes.  How say Harry steps on the gum, so it is stuck between his shoes (inside the cloak and hidden from others) and floor (outside the cloak and visible to others).  Is the gum visible to others or not?  If he lifts up that shoe, what happens if a) the gum is stuck to the shoe or b) the gum remains stuck to the floor?